# Admob video rewards ad limit per day

Tags: java, android, admob

Implemented a video reward ad with admob on my proyect, and want to know if i should set a limit to watch ads on my activity or should set it inside the dashboard of admob?
in each case, it will reset at 00:00 UTC automatically? or should i do it by code.

```
ads1.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (mRewardedAd != null) {
            mRewardedAd.show(MainActivity2.this, rewardItem -> {
                int rewardAmount = rewardItem.getAmount();
                String rewardType = rewardItem.getType();
             
                UsersRef.child(currentUserID).child("diamonds").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.exists()) {
                            try {
                                int diamonds = snapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
                                diamonds = diamonds + 1;
                                counter.setText("" + diamonds);
                                UsersRef.child(currentUserID).child("diamonds").setValue(diamonds);

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else {
                            UsersRef.child(currentUserID).child("diamonds").setValue(1);
                            counter.setText("1");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
                
            });


        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "The rewarded ad wasn't ready yet.");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the AdMob 'Frequency capping' built-in feature, because you can modify the number of ads each users sees per minute / hour / day quite easily and it resets automatically, without needing to query your own server, make updates to the app or write additional code. (aka don't reinvent the wheel)

You can read more about AdMob frequency capping [here](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/4377690?hl=en), and about capping ad units [here](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6244508#adunits).

Comment: So from i understand, no need to set a button with a counter to limit the ads, just set a limit of views inside the configuration of admob. But how can i test if its works properly? because the test ad is showing the ad always, no matter if i put a limit of views. And the other question would be, if i watch 5 ads at 15:00 hs, the system will lock the ads and unlock at 00:00 hs or at 15:00 of the next day? Thanks and sorry for the questions, is my first time with admob

Comment: AdMob puts Frequency capping on real ads and not on test ads. If you watch 5 ads at 15:00 the system will unlock at 15:00 the next day if you put a frequency cap of 5 ads / 24 hours and unlock at 00:00 if you set the cap to daily.
You can't really test if the cap works or not, you can just trust AdMob that the cap will work properly.